# Importing classes from another app in Django

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.10 for my project. Below is the project structure.

```
project
|-accounts
|  |-forms
|  |  |-__init__.py
|  |  |-user_forms.py
|-otherapp
|  |-views.py
```

I have define `UserForm` class in `user_forms.py` file and in `__init__.py` file I imported `user_forms` as `from .user_forms import *`
I am trying to use `UserForm` in `otherapp`.
I was just curious why

```
from accounts.form import UserForm
form = UserForm(request.POST)
```

works but

```
import accounts.forms.UserForm
form = UserForm(request.POST)
```

or

```
form = accounts.form.UserForm(request.POST)
```

does not work?  Why?

Isn't 3rd method better than first two as it follows zen of python `Explicit is better than implicit`.

What is the best way to import classes from one app to other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `import accounts.forms.UserForm` because `UserForm` is a class, not a module. You can however do:

```
import accounts.forms
form = accounts.form.UserForm(request.POST)
```

Personally, I prefer your first approach. As long as `UserForm` doesn't clash with another `UserForm` from `account.views` it won't cause any problems. The import shows you where it has been imported from, so I don't think 'Explicit is better than implicit' is an issue here.

```
from accounts.form import UserForm
form = UserForm(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we `import` anything python search for the named module not for `class` or `function`. `UserForm` is a class according to you, thats why `import accounts.forms.UserForm` is not working. You can also do it by:

```
from accounts.forms import *
form = UserForm(request.POST)
```

For more on `import` statement you can go https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

Comment: Star imports like `from accounts.forms import *` are discouraged -- it makes it harder to see where imports are coming from.